# How to create CellStyle for workbook that is created using WorkbookFactory?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a java code where I have to compare two excel sheets regardless of the format ( xls or xlsx) and copy the rows that differ to a new excel sheet. Then I read about WorkbookFactory which would accept both format.
 **Below is the code snippet I created : Please help!!**

```
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;

    class Compare extends CopyRow
    {   
     //<-------VARIABLES DECLARATION & INITIALISATION----->

      Workbook outputWorkbook,workbook1,workbook2;
 Sheet excel1Sheet,excel2Sheet,newSheet;

       public void compare(String fileA,String fileB)

         {
    try
    {
      if(fileA.endsWith(".xls")outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/eclipse/workspace/CompareExcelV2/output.xls"));
else
outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/eclipse/workspace/CompareExcelV2/output.xlsx"))
      workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileA));
      workbook2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileB));

      CellStyle excel1Red = new workbook1.createCellStyle(); **//ERROR HERE**
 CellStyle excel2Green = new workbook2.createCellStyle(); **//ERROR HERE**
      CellStyle newStyle = new outputWorkbook.createCellStyle();**//ERROR HERE**

     }
   catch {}
```

}

I am not able to create CellStyle. I get the following error:

`workbook1 cannot be resolved to a type`

`workbook2 cannot be resolved to a type`

`outputWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your code:

```
if(fileA.endsWith(".xls")outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/eclipse/workspace/CompareExcelV2/output.xls"));
else outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:/Documents and Settings/eclipse/workspace/CompareExcelV2/output.xlsx"))
workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileA));
workbook2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileB));
```

Then there's a few things. One is that [opening from a File is lower memory than from a stream](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), the second is that your code doesn't seem to be doing what you want. You appear to be opening `outputWorkbook` based on a file, when I suspect you just want a new empty one that you later save. Instead, how about something like:

```
final String path = "C:/Documents and Settings/eclipse/workspace/CompareExcelV2/";
Workbook outputWorkbook;
FileOutputStream outputTo;
if (fileA.endsWith(".xls") {
   outputWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
   outputTo = new FileOutputStream(path + "output.xls");
} else {
   outputWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   outputTo = new FileOutputStream(path + "output.xlsx");
}
Workbook workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileA));
Workbook workbook2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileB));
```

Finally, make sure you have all the right jars on your classpath, see [the Components and their Dependencies section](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on the POI website for details

Comment: Thanks for the help! @Gagravarr I found the issue with CellStyle also, I was trying to initialise CellStyle using(my bad) `excel1Red = new workbook1.createCellStyle();` so compiler was looking for a constructor named `workbook1`. Also, workbookFactory cannot create a new excel? It can only read excel files?. If so, if I compare a `.xls` and `.xlsx` file, according to my code it will create a `.xls` output file as it is `fileA`, so will there be a problem in writing output to the output file because of `fileB`. Please enlighten me, I'm new to Java and Apache POI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WorkbookFactory` creates the appropriate kind of Workbook based on a given input, saving you from having to check. For output, if you're starting with a new file, only you know what kind you want, so it's up to you to initialize the appropriate one of `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook` as per your own needs / requirements